# AJAX to populate date input: date does not confirm to required format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: ajax, date, format

Similar questions have been asked but this is different because my date format appears to be correct. I am attempting to change the value of an HTML date input field, depending on the value a user selects in another input field. 
The HTML code is as follows (the initial value is set as the current date)``:

```
        <input type = "date" id = "endDate" name = "endDate" class = "filterLW" value = "<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
```

The AJAX call is as follows:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    //get the new academic year
     $("#academicYear").change(function(e){
         var academicYear = $(this).val();
         //make the AJAX call, passing the new academic year to php 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getEndDate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ({'academicYear': academicYear}),
                async: true,
                success: function(value){
                         //repopulate the end date input value
                         alert(value); //for testing
                         $('#endDate').val(value);
                    },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                         alert(xhr.status + " "+thrownError);
                }
          });
        });
   });
```

The error message is below:

[image]

So, the format appears to be in the correct format but the error message says it isn't. Sorry if this is obvious - I'm new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\r\n` is a carriage return, a newline, and two spaces at the front of your date.   Try using trim..

```
$('#endDate').val($.trim(value));
```

Comment: Many thanks - I did try to trim in PHP and it had no effect, but you are absolutely right - trimming in JavaScript/jQuery solves the problem. Many thanks. I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation points yet(!) to upvote, but your solution is the one.